# Spacing out legend keys using tmap/ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, tmap, geom

I'm trying to produce a map using either the tmap or ggplot2 packages and need to follow some internal design guidelines which state that legend keys should be spaced out and rectangular in shape.

I have tried tmap but the legend keys are square and stacked on top of each other without any spacing. I cannot figure out how to change the shape to rectangles and how to space out the keys.

In ggplot2, I get rectangles but the spacing seems to be fixed. Is there a way to space the keys out in ggplot2 (or tmap)?

```
theme_opts <- list(theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.background = element_blank(),
                     plot.background = element_blank(),
                     panel.border = element_blank(),
                     axis.line = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                     axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                     axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                     legend.position=c(0.015, 0.7),
                     legend.background = element_rect(fill=alpha("white", 0)),
                     legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
                     legend.key.height = unit(0.2, "cm"),
                     legend.spacing.y = unit(1, "cm"),
                     legend.title = element_text(size=14,  family="Tahoma"),
                     legend.text = element_text(size=12,  family="Tahoma")))

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = map_data_full, aes(fill = TransmissionClassification), size = 0.5, color = "gray10") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours, breaks = transmission_levels) +
  geom_sf(data = map_data_borders, fill = NA, size = 1, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(1405044, 7120890), ylim = c(1291822, 5218781)) +
  theme_opts
```

This is how the legend looks:

[image: This is how the legend looks]

And this is what I would like:

[image: And this is what I would like]

Comment: Does something like this help? Some code would be good. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562542/how-to-fix-vertical-space-in-crowded-tmap-legend-r

Comment: Thanks - since then I have tried ggplot but got stuck with the same problem. I'll try again with tmap. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No luck. Doesn't really work. Updating the question with the ggplot code.

Comment: maybe this if you are using ggplot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275113/ggplot2-increase-space-between-legend-keys

Comment: Could you provide an image with the desire output?

Comment: Thanks @OrlandoSabogal I included an image.

Comment: Thanks @william3031 - I saw that but doesn't seem to work with shape keys.